# Trying to assert 2 dynamic responses

Tags: karate

I have 2 different responses:

```
{
      "id": "U204204",
      "title": "Safety kit",
      "categoryPath": "/equipment/accessories/null",
      "keyFeature": false,
      "description": "test",
      "price": 24.5,
      "availability": "optional-extra",
      "technologyItems": [],
      "bespoke": false
    }
```

or/and

```
{
      "id": "GWW1WW1",
      "title": "Winter pack",
      "categoryPath": "/comfort & convenience/packs/null",
      "keyFeature": false,
      "description": "test",
      "price": 410,
      "availability": "optional-extra",
      "technologyItems": [],
      "bespoke": false
    }
```

Now what I'm trying to assert is as long as the key **price** in ANY of the 2 responses above has a value ending in '.5' pass it.

I have tried the following and **similar** things but not working:

```
Given path 'endpoint'
    And multipart file pdbData =  { read: 'json/PostRequest_201_3.json', filename: 'PostRequest_201_3.json', contentType: 'application/json'}
    When method post
    And status 201
    * def NewpdbId = response.id
    And path 'endpoint'+NewpdbId+'/V3FOY3DG'
    And method GET
    And status 200
    * string aa = response.options[13].price
    * string bb = response.options[16].price

    * def expected = aa contains "#redgex .+[.5]+" ? { pass: true  } 
    * def expected = bb contains "#regex .+[.5]+" ? { pass: true } 

    * string expected = expected


    And match expected == { pass: true }
```

So if the key **price** ends in '.5' in any of the responses it should be a pass.  If key **price** is a whole number in **all** of the responses then it should fail.

Any ideas? I have tried so many different ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways. Read the docs for [`match each`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each) also:

First extract only the `price` values into a list, convert to strings (read the docs for [JSON transforms](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms)):

```
* def prices = $response.options[*].price
* def fun = function(x){ return x + '' }
* def prices = karate.map(prices, fun)
* match prices contains '#regex .+[.5]+'
```